# is there any JavaScript interpretor that can handle very large numbers?

Tags: javascript, bignum

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a bignum library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript)
>   [Strange syntax of Number methods in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860998/strange-syntax-of-number-methods-in-javascript)

I just wrote some code  to figure out a [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) question.

I kept getting...

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I couldn't *see* the syntax error in my code...

The number I'm using is 1000 digits long. I ran in Chrome's console

```
Number.MAX_VALUE >  7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

And got `false`. Bummer.

Is there a interpreter that can run my code?

Here is the code if needed...

```
var num = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450.toString();

var max = 0,
    length = num.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     
     var consecTotal = 1,
         limit = i + 5;
      
      for (var j = i; j < limit; j++) {
        consecTotal *= parseInt(num.substr(j, 1), 10);
      }
      
      max = Math.max(max, consecTotal);
      
}

console.log(max);
```

The question is to find the largest number that is the product of 5 consecutive numbers. I won't type it word for word, as I think Project Euler frowns upon answers being posted online (I'm not even sure mine may work yet).

I turned to JavaScript because I wasn't sure how to set up an `int` to handle the number in C.

Comment: @Josh: Also, [this is related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860998/strange-syntax-of-number-methods-in-javascript/1861033#1861033)

Comment: @Roatin Ha, I didn't even notice that in his code snippet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To actually explain the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

The cause of this is actually that...

```
...20752963450.toString();
              ^-------- ...the dot after a number is treated as a decimal point
                        Therefore this doesn't make sense.
                        But if you add a space in front of the dot, then it will work because
                        now JavaScript uses it to access the toString() method.

12323 .toString() // this will work as you'd expect it to if you come from Ruby or the like
```

Still, if you add the space `num` will be infinity. So you'll have to look at awoodland's answer for a BigNum implementation.

Comment: +1 for me failing to spot that problem!

Comment: You can also use `(123).toString()` or `123.0.toString()` http://stackoverflow.com/q/1860998/54420

Comment: @Josh Indeed, but `()` looks a bit redundant and the `.0` looks quite strange to me. Although people who don't know about the problem might just strip out any of the three because they think it's redundant / a typo.

Comment: Is `200 + ''` a good solution to [cast to string](http://jsfiddle.net/y2QbQ/)?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a big num class. It seems there's one for [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript) and if you want to do it in C you could use [gmp](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

First, your num variable should be a proper string literal if you want to use it as a string. Which is what you appear to be doing. I've never seen the notation you are trying to use there and I can't get it to work in Chrome or IE.  Just use:

```
var num = '73167176531330....';
```

Second, your inner loop is never going to terminate.  j will always be less than j + 5.  Did you perhaps mean j < i + 5?

Third, you'll need to make your outer loop only go to i < length - 4.  Otherwise you are going to overrun then end of your "num" string in your inner loop when i gets close to the end length.

If I make those changes I get an answer.  I don't know if it is the answer you are seeking.

Comment: Inner loop code updated already.

Comment: Looks like you changed the code a bit before I posted to address my second issue. :)

Comment: I don't think it matters about overrunning when I use `parseInt()`. Those `undefined` should be cast to `0`. This will make that equation 0, which is fine because none of those numbers will match the requirements.

Comment: @Alex Even if it does produce 0, it is habitual for me to look for fencepost errors that's why I mentioned it.  Cheers!